# Can't create project via angular-cli

Tags: angular, npm

I use the command `ng new projectName` and then, when it comes to the point where I have the message `installing packages via npm`, it hangs forever. I used the command `npm cache clean` but doesn't solve the issue.

```
Update:
```

I waited long enough and get the error message from the terminal:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/compiler@2.1.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 wants @angular/compiler@2.0.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.1.0 wants @angular/compiler@2.1.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Chaklader/Documents/Online Education/Egghead/AngularJS/Getting Started/myProject/npm-debug.log
```

I use Mac OS for the project

Comment: It takes a while. How long did you wait?

Comment: Around 5 minutes how long I should wait to report an issue ? When I was trying webStrom, it was also the same issue there.

Comment: More than 5 minutes. Probably no more than (to be safe) 20 minutes. There's a lot they are downloading when they install the node modules

Comment: Thanks for this info. 20 minutes to start a project!!!! Will it be same for every time I start a new project?

Comment: Yup. Because each new project gets it's own node_modules that need to be downloaded

Comment: Do you think I can keep a copy of the project folder after npm installation and use it over and over ? There should be all the packages installed. Or there may be something as quick-start there

Comment: Yeah I'm sure you could. You just need to change some names around, because CLI names some things based on the project name you supply.

Comment: Do you think I can then take in the webStorm and refractor the project name. That should refractor all the names inside as well.